# Cordova App shows "Connection Type Unknown" while wifi is on

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

Hey I am trying to check my network state on cordova. When my state is   **4g, 3g, No Network** my app gives the correct alert however on wifi it says connection unknown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <title>Our Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
        }
        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div data-role="page" id="main">
        <div data-role="header" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

interestingly I've tried full example given on API documentation (even though my code is almost same as the example ) 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

same error happens here too.
just in case I am sharing my device information too.

**My Phone : Sony Xperia Z 
Model : C6603 
Android Version : 4.2.2 
Compile Number : 10.31.A.2.67**

Comment: I just tested your code with Cordova 3.2.0rc1, Android 4.4, Nexus 5 phone, and it worked fine (alerted 'WiFi connection')... I installed the plugin with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`. There hasn't been any updates to that plugin in a while so I don't think that's the problem. Can you try on a different device or emulator to see if it's a problem with the Xperia?

Comment: Do you have permissions set in config.xml? <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

Comment: yes I do have this permission in config.xml. also if I didn't have this permission I couldn't check other network states.